# Trying to download from a dynamic link with C#

Tags: c#, webclient

I need some help to download a file from a link that is half unknown. Admitting we have this website www.website.com/fileX_Y.txt and X , Y are two int between 0 and 20. I gave it a try and my code will keep creating files and replacing older one by a empty one so I cant figure out the correct one. Sorry for my bad english :D
''

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp13
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < 20; y++)
                    {
                        string uri = "lieen" + x + "_ " + y + ".extension";
                        string path = "C:\\json\\" + x + y + ".txt";
                        WebClient client = new WebClient();
                        try
                        {
                            client.DownloadFile(uri, path);
                        }
                        catch (WebException wex)
                        {
                            if (((HttpWebResponse)wex.Response).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                            {

                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your destination path is causing collisions:

```
string path = "C:\\json\\" + x + y + ".txt";
```

if x = 11 and y = 0, it will give the same path as when x = 1 and y = 10.

Change it to add a delimiter between x and y.

```
string path = "C:\\json\\" + x + "_" + y + ".txt";
```

The i is also a problem because you are trying the same files up to 20 times.  No reason to do that.

Comment: still, it will not cancel the fact that at each try it replaces the old file. admit that 0_2 is the correct guess it will be automatically replaced by 0_3 and next...

Comment: still not sure what your i variable is for...and why you have an empty try/catch

Comment: because i dont know the right combination of the link it can be 0_1 or 19_1 . and instead of trying manually i'm trying this way

Comment: catch is to avoid app craching since it will be a lot of 404 errors

Comment: If your web exception isn't not found...you want to rethrow it

Comment: didnt fully get you :(

Comment: You might have other exceptions that just not found...this code catches them and does nothing to let the caller proc know there's a problem...that can cause confusion

Answer (score 0):

As file names are getting similar it is getting replaced. You can follow this approach as append Date Time before file name so if your code run again then also it will not get replaced.

```
string path = "C:\\json\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy-HHmmss") + " " + x + "_" + y + ".txt";
```

Comment: still, it replace old file